# Vector Field Conceptual Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given that:
$$F = \langle yz-2xy^2, axz-2x^2y+z, xy+y \rangle$$
in which $a$ is some constant.

Now, for what $a$ would make the vector field of $F$ conservative? Why is there only one, or are there many? How can we find an $f$ with $\nabla f=F$? Also for what $a$ would $F$ be the curl of another vector field?

For to find for which $a$ the vector field is conservative, do we have to go through the process of finding partial derivative, or is there a much shorter approach. I don't know how to approach my other questions either.

Comment: "long process of finding partial derivative". It's really so long for you? You want to find some magic method?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Wrong choice of words. Sorry

Comment: a necessary condition: the Jacobian of $F$ is symmetric.

Comment: or just integrate

Comment: @user251257 Can you show what you mean?

Comment: if there is such a $f$, it's hessian will be symmetric

Comment: @user251257 Okay, so say that it is symmetric, how would I continue on with this problem?

Comment: you still need to integrate, if you want to find $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\i}{\hat{\mathbf{i}}}
\newcommand{\j}{\hat{\mathbf{j}}}
\newcommand{\k}{\hat{\mathbf{k}}}
\renewcommand{\p}{\partial\,}
\renewcommand{\b}{\begin}
\renewcommand{\e}{\end}
\renewcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
$

### 1. Determine if $\boldsymbol F$ is conservative

**HINT**: Recall for any scalar vector field $f$ is the [**curl of its gradient is zero**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_of_the_gradient): 
$ \nabla \times \big( \nabla f \big) = 0 $.

Since $ F$ is conservative iff $\ \exists\; f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ such that $F = \nabla f$, we can easily check if such $f$ exists by taking curl of $F$ and comparing it to zero

> If you are not convinced in the accuracy of the last statement, I propose to address something like [**this website**](http://mathinsight.org/conservative_vector_field_determine).

Indeed,

- $\Rightarrow $ If $F$ is conservative, then $\exists$ a scalar field $f $ s.t. $F = \nabla f$. 
  Taking curl of both sides of the last equality, we get 
  $ \nabla \times F = \nabla \times \big(\nabla f\big) = 0$. 
  Thus we established that 
  $$
   \boxed{ \ F \ \text{ is conservative } \implies \nabla \times F = 0 \ }
   $$
- $\Leftarrow$  If $\nabla \times F  = 0$, then $F$ is conservative, because a vector field is conservative if and only if it is [**irrotational**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields), which equivalent to $F$ [**having zero curl**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConservativeField.html) in 3D space. 
  Therefore we can write 
  $$ \boxed{ \ \nabla \times F  = 0 \implies  \exists \, f \ \text{ s.t. } \ F = \nabla f \iff F \ \text{ is conservative } \ }$$

---

#### 1.1 Solution

Now, let us use these facts in order to determine value of parameter $a$ for which your vector field 
$$
F = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
F_x \\  F_y \\ F_z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
yz-2xy^2 \\  axz-2x^2y+z \\  xy+y 
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
is conservative.
In other words, we need to find values of $a$ such that the curl of $F$ will be zero.

Denote $\i, \j, \k$ orthonormal basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$. Then the curl of $F$ can be computed as

$$
\nabla \times F = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\i & \j & \k \\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ 
F_x & F_y & F_z
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\left(\dfrac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}-\dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial z}\right)\i +
\left(\dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial z}-\dfrac{\partial F_z}{\partial x}\right)\j +
\left(\dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}\right)\k. 
$$
Let us compute partial derivatives of $F_x, F_y, F_z$ components of $F$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} & = z - 4 xy, & 
\dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} & = y 
\\
\dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} & = a z - 4 x y &
\dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} & = a x + 1 
\\
\dfrac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} & = y &
\dfrac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} & = x + 1
\end{aligned}
$$

Substituting it into the $\nabla \times F$ formula, we get
$$
\nabla \times F = 
\Big(\left(x+1\right) - \left(ax + 1\right) \Big)\i +
\Big( y - y \Big)\j +
\Big(\left( az - 4 xy \right) - \left(z - 4 xy\right) \Big)\k = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(1-a\right) x \\ 0 \\ \left( a - 1 \right) z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If $F$ is a *conservation field*, then $\nabla \times F =  0 $ *for any* $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3$, so we write

$$
\nabla \times F 
= \begin{bmatrix} \left(1-a\right) x \\ 0 \\ \left( a - 1 \right) z \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}  \ \forall \, x,y,z \in \mathbb R \implies \boxed{ \ a - 1 = 0 \ }
$$

Therefore we finally conclude that $F$ is conservation field if and only if $ a = 1   $.

---

### 2. Find potential function for  $\boldsymbol F$

In the section above we established that $F$ is *conservative* for $a=1$, i.e. that there exists a *potential function* $f:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ such that 
$$
\nabla f = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{\p f}{\p x} \\ \frac{\p f}{\p x} \\ \frac{\p f}{\p x} 
\end{matrix}\right]
= F\vert_{a=1} =
\left.\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
F_x \\ F_y \\ F_z
\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right|_{a=1} 
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
yz-2xy^2 \\  xz-2x^2y+z \\  xy+y 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Thus, one can find potential function $f$ by integrating components of $F$ and matching results.

---

#### 2.1 Solution

First, integrate $F_x = \dfrac{\p f}{\p x} $ with respect to variable $x$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\p f}{\p x} &= yz - 2xy^2 
&&\implies& f(x,y,z) &= yz - x^2 y^2 + h_(y,z),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $h$ is unknown functions of $y$ and $z$.

Second, differentiate obtained expression w.r.t. $y$ and compare to $F_y$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\p f}{\p y} = F_y 
& \implies 
\frac{\p }{\p y} \Big(yz - x^2 y^2 + h(y,z)\Big) 
=z - 2x^2 y + \frac{\p }{\p y} h(y,z)
= axz - 2 x^2y + z
\\ & \implies 
\frac{\p }{\p y} h(y,z) = axz \implies h(y,z) = axyz + g(z)
\\ & \implies
f(x,y,z) = yz - x^2 y^2 + axyz + g(z)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $g$ is unknown functions of  $z$.

Third, we differentiate obtained expression for $f$  w.r.t. $z$ and match it to $F_z$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\p f}{\p z} = F_z 
& \implies 
\frac{\p }{\p z} \big(yz - x^2 y^2 + xyz + g(z)\big) 
= y + xy + \frac{\p }{\p z} g(z)
= xy + y
\\ & \implies 
\frac{\p }{\p z} g(z) = 0 \implies g(z) = c \ \ - \operatorname{const}
\\ & \implies
f(x,y,z) = yz - x^2 y^2 + xyz + c 
\end{aligned}
$$
where $c\in \R$ is an arbitrary constant.

Thus we have obtained the potential of $F$:

$$
\boxed{ \ \ f  = (1-x) yz - x^2 y^2 + c \ \ }
$$

---

### 3. Determine  if $\boldsymbol F$ is a curl of another vector field

**HINT**: Recall that the [divergence of a curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Divergence_of_the_curl) of any vector field is zero:  $\forall \ A:\R^3 \to  \R^3 \quad  \nabla \cdot \big( \nabla \times  A\big) \equiv 0$.

Therefore in order to establish whether $F$ is a curl of another vector field it is sufficient to check whether $\nabla \cdot F = 0 $ for all $ (x,y,z) \in \R^3$.

---

#### 2.1 Solution

All we need to do is to compute  divergence of $F$, and find out if there values of  $a$ for which $\nabla \cdot F \equiv 0$.

$$
\nabla\cdot F = 
\dfrac{\p F_x}{\p x} + \dfrac{\p F_y}{\p y} + \dfrac{\p F_z}{\p z} =
\dfrac{\p }{\p x} \Big(yz-2xy^2 \Big) 
+ \dfrac{\p }{\p y} \Big( axz-2x^2y+z \Big)
+ \dfrac{\p }{\p z} \Big(  xy+y \Big) = 
-2y^2 - 2 x^2  + 0 
\not \equiv 0
$$

Therefore we conclude that $F$ is **not** a curl of any other vector field.

Comment: For the question, "is there any value of a such that F is the curl of some other vector field" is it for any value of a?

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: @gauss'sson The easiest way to answer this question is to use [the fact that the divergence of a curl of any vector field is zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Divergence_of_the_curl): $\ \forall \ A:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3 \ \ \nabla \cdot \big( \nabla \times A \big) \equiv 0$.  Can you pick it up from here, or do you need me to write it out?

Answer (score 2):

In order to determine *a* so that $\vec{f}$ is conservative, you must find:

$$
\oint \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{l} = 0
$$

$$
\int _{x_1} ^{x_2} F_x dx + \int _{y_1} ^{y_2} F_{y} dy + \int _{z_1} ^ {z_2} F_{z} dz = 0
$$

For the second question:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = F_x
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = F_y
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = F_z
$$

Now you must solve the set of partial differential equation.

Comment: Can you please expand on this?

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: The third one isn't

Comment: Are you having a conceptual problem or you can't find the differential equation solution (you know what to do but for some reason, you can't solve it)?

Comment: conceptual problem

Comment: My question is, that is there any value of a such that F is the curl of some other vector field?