# Necessary and sufficient for vector field to be conservative

Tags: reference-request, vector-fields, potential-theory

I found the following statement in [this](https://youtu.be/KXpYRnZ60nM?t=1900) youtube lecture:

> Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and convex and let
>   $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable vector field.
>
> Then $f$ is conservative iff the Jacobian of $f$ is symmetric on $A$.

I couldn't find a citable reference for this (for $n\ne3$).

Does someone have one?

Update: I'm still looking for a citable reference.

Comment: See whether [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383229/vector-field-conceptual-question) helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ conservative means exist an scalar field $\phi$ with $f = \nabla\phi$. Apply now [Schwarz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives). For the reverse implication see my (a bit more general) answer in [Poincaré lemma for star shaped domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838192/poincar%C3%A9-lemma-for-star-shaped-domain/2838193).

Reference: *Fundamentals of Differential Geometry* by Serge Lang. Theorem 4.1 of chap. V.

Comment: @snoozzz, see the edit.