# Conservative fields

Tags: vectors

Prove that **F** is conservative iff it is irrotational.
That is **F** is conservative then it is irrotational and if **F** is irrotational then it is conservative.
The 1st part is easy to show. In the second part, I have shown that
∂F_3/∂y=∂F_2/∂z. Similarly the other two partial derivatives are equal. How does one show that Φ is the scalar potential associated with **F** i.e. **F**= gradΦ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thank you. I have mentioned uptill where I was able to think about the proof. I hope the minor edits that I've made to the question fits in well with your advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Necessary and sufficient for vector field to be conservative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3355315/necessary-and-sufficient-for-vector-field-to-be-conservative)

Comment: I'm not sure as I'm not well versed with the concepts mentioned there. I'm still learning the basics of vector calculus and calculus as a subject in general. Thank you though!